# LogRotate: error running non-shared postrotate script

Tags: linux, logrotate

During Daily Log Rotation, we are getting below error.

`/usr/bin/find: cannot delete ‘/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out’: Permission denied
error: error running non-shared postrotate script for /var/log/tomcat/xdlogger.log of '/var/log/tomcat/*.log'`

Here is my logrotate configuration.

```
# cat /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat
/var/log/tomcat/*.txt
/var/log/tomcat/*.log
/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out {
    copytruncate
    daily
    dateext
    rotate 3
    compress
    missingok
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/find /var/log/tomcat/ -type f ! -name 'catalina.out' -mtime +5 -delete
    endscript
}
```

Permissions for catalina.out and xdlogger.log is as follows.

```
# stat /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out
  File: `/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out'
  Size: 16061           Blocks: 32         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd05h/64773d    Inode: 41          Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (   70/     www)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-07-11 03:17:16.056809957 -0500
Modify: 2019-07-11 07:14:48.331588384 -0500
Change: 2019-07-11 07:14:48.331588384 -0500

# stat /var/log/tomcat/xdlogger.log
  File: `/var/log/tomcat/xdlogger.log'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd05h/64773d    Inode: 1433        Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (   70/     www)   Gid: (   70/     www)
Access: 2019-07-11 03:17:16.044810362 -0500
Modify: 2019-07-11 03:17:16.044810362 -0500
Change: 2019-07-11 03:17:16.044810362 -0500
```

Let me know where i am going wrong.

Comment: There's no `Context` line in the `stat` output; just to confirm, does `ls -l /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out` show a period between the permission set and the owner (www)?

Comment: They're much easier to read in the question....

Comment: It's CentOS 6, so there is no context in stat command. SElinux permissions are shown below. 
`# ls -lZ /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out
-rwxr-xr-x. www root unconfined_u:object_r:tomcat_log_t:s0 /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out`

`# ls -lZ /var/log/tomcat/xdlogger.log
-rwxr-xr-x. www www unconfined_u:object_r:tomcat_log_t:s0 /var/log/tomcat/xdlogger.log`

`# ls -l /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 www root 154 Jul 12 03:45 /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out`

`# ls -l /var/log/tomcat/xdlogger.log
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 www www 0 Jul 12 03:33 /var/log/tomcat/xdlogger.log`